# How can I handle touch with a CCScene and a CCButton inside him

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I'm trying to make a menu with buttons and I want to handle the touch events with all at the same time.

The problem is that if I press the button, the `touchBegan` event doesn't be called in the `CCScene`. I have enabled the touch management in the scene and it works, but it seems like the button blocks the event.

```
[self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
CCButton *pButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"btn"];
[self addChild:pButton];
```

I want to use it to make a menu with a list of buttons bigger than the screen and lets the user to do scroll on the list, but the buttons block the touch callbacks and I can't manage the scroll effect.

Anybody know how can I set the button to let the `CCScene` manage the touch events in this situation?

Comment: you may want to explain why you want to do this (unclear to me). Is it really a button ? Knowing your design intent will help people to offer better suggestions ... if any :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Set same selector for all the buttons and distinguish them with tags;

```
CCButton *pButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"btn"];
pButton.tag = 1;
[pButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(buttonHandler:)];
[self addChild: pButton];
```

**Solution 2:**
Do not use buttons. Use CCSprite and at touchBegin check for intersects;

```
CGRectContainsPoint(spriteRect, touchPoint);
```

Comment: After many tests I have choosen the second solution, because I didn't found if this situaction can be managed with the current cocos2d library. Thanks